# Google Apps Script : API Error message "client_id is required"

Tags: google-apps-script

I've created a variable to hold the client ID (CLIENT_ID) but I keep getting an error message saying that the client ID is required when running this function. Anyone have any idea of what I've done wrong here?

```
function getAuth() {
  var authBasedUrl = 'https://test-api.service.hmrc.gov.uk/oauth/authorize';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(authBasedUrl,  {
      headers: {
        'Accept' : 'application/vnd.hmrc.1.0+json',
        'response_type': 'code',
        'client_id' : CLIENT_ID,
        'scope' : 'hello',
        'redirect_uri' : 'https://www.xxxxxxx.com/'
      }});
  var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [docs](https://developer.service.hmrc.gov.uk/api-documentation/docs/authorisation/application-restricted-endpoints) you need to make a POST request. There is a blockqoute on the page that says:

> Include the request parameters in the request body, not as request
> headers.

**EDIT:**

```
function getAuth() {
  var authBasedUrl = 'https://test-api.service.hmrc.gov.uk/oauth/token';
  var options = {
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/vnd.hmrc.1.0+json',
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    payload: JSON.stringify({
      client_id: 'RgwU6hvdxxxxxxic6LwIt',
      client_secret: '9e8c9yyyyyyyyyyc2fc2ed9126',
      grant_type: 'client_credentials',
      scope: 'hello'
    })
  }
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(authBasedUrl, options);
  var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to run your code however another error message came up: "Exception: Request failed for test-api.service.hmrc.gov.uk returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"client_id is required"} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)" any idea why this would be a problem? I did set the client ID and Secret

Comment: I've updated the code. I got a token when i tested it. I missed the content-type

Comment: I've run the code with my Client ID and Secret and its working, thanks!

Comment: Please mark the answer. @h-edwards